# pointer-events: none; does not work as expected

Tags: css

Edit: *with the help of the example of @josephting below i was able to reproduce the exact same problem: https://codepen.io/WaxL/pen/qBEzadp In the top half of red the events work, in the bottom half where its overlapped by the anchor not*

On a page with fixed header i need to offset the anchors so that they are displayed correctly. I found a solution that is reported to work on multiple resources:

```
.elementor-menu-anchor:before {
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height: 150px !important; 
    margin: -150px 0 0 !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none !important;
  }
```

What does not work unfortunately is the `pointer-events: none`. If there is anything clickable in the 150px before the anchor it is overlayed by the block and not clickable. From all I researched pointer-events:none is supposed to let all clicks through to whatever is below.
What could be the reason that this is not working?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do, can you post a working example or the html?

Comment: `pointer-events: none` passes the event to parent element, not overlaid element. [(Ref)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) That said, moving your element up by 150px cannot pass the event to another element. [Sample](https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/gObJQJZ)

Comment: Oh, thats the reason, thank you @josephting, just post this as answer. Is there an alternative to make this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so I can't say.

Comment: @Dejan.S i have a working example now. Sorry for the missing context

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), `pointer-events: none` passes the event to parent element, not overlaid element.

**Characteristics**

- Event will be pass through to parent regardless of `pointer-events`
- Elements with `pointer-events: none` specified only disable its own event

See [Sample](https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/gObJQJZ)

- Green square has `pointer-events: none`
- Yellow square **does not* have `pointer-events: none`

**Things to try on [sample page](https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/gObJQJZ)**

1. Clicking on red square will trigger red event
2. Clicking on green square that is above red square will trigger red event
3. Clicking on green square that is outside red square will not trigger red event
4. Clicking on yellow square will trigger both yellow and red event
5. Clicking on black square that is behind container of green and red square will not trigger black event
6. Clicking on black square below the red square will trigger black event

If you want certain element to trigger another event on completely different element, you need to do that with JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector('#a').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#b').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
});
```

I've added a stranger button to trigger red event on the sample page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. So I have a different problem then. I tried to modify your example so it looks like mine. [https://codepen.io/WaxL/pen/qBEzadp](https://codepen.io/WaxL/pen/qBEzadp) In my original problem i get nothing when i click on the green area over the red area. In this test thingy here it works (red). So probably some oversight. I tried to find  something with inspect on chrome, but I dont see anything suspicous. Of course elementor adds a lot of css. Additional thing I tried is modifying z-index of the elements, but this does not work either

Comment: I did it now @josephting, i was able to reproduce the issue. i saved it over the pen link below [https://codepen.io/WaxL/pen/qBEzadp](https://codepen.io/WaxL/pen/qBEzadp) You see that in the 100 px where myanchor overlaps red the events are not triggered, even if pointer-events: none is active. In top half where there is no overlap red triggers, in the bottom half not

Comment: @WaxL It's not supposed to. You have to add event listener to `#myanchor` to send click event to `#red` in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: so because of '#red' is not the parent of '#myanchor' the event is getting 'lost' even though there is pointer-events: none? what could be a solution? I want the click to go to whatever is below '#myanchor'. In the real scenario i cannot add a handler because i dont know what is below each anchor, that will change frequently too

Comment: @WaxL If you want to decorate some links or buttons by overlaying something, do it as a child of the element you want clicked. Not entirely separate element. Eg. You want to overlay something to click `#red` then you add a child in `#red`.

Comment: The entire point of the whole thing is to offset every anchor by the size of the fixed header (otherwise the headline/anchor would be behind the fixed header). But if I offset every anchor by 200px, it can cover anything thats on the page before that, i cannot make every anchor a client of the previous page content. If i cannot make the anchor box 'click through' i would need to find a different solution for the fixed header/anchor problem itself, but all solutions i can find rely on a div being shifted over the previous content